# Error in GenomeInfoDb library while trying to use Biostrings

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm trying to use the library Biostring for some fasta files analysis of virus, when I try to use the package the console displays an error:

```
library(Biostring)  # your input
# --------------console output
Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GenomeInfoDb’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘RCurl’
Error: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ could not be loaded
```

I'm using rstudio on windows.

I need to use a DNAstring vector on my problem, for that I need Biostrings library to work properly.

Comment: Did you try installing `RCurl` package?

Comment: Please read: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please read the error message and pay attention to the portion of the error message that tells you there is a missing package required by pkg:'GenomeInfoDb'. How are you installing your BioConductor packages. You should be using BiocManager, which generally alerts you to the issue of missing packages.